# Need help figuring out why Powershell is throwing error 16

Tags: powershell, syntax-error

I posted this script [the other day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402898/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-save-as-a-different-file-extension) in an effort to discover a good way to change file extensions when "saving as." I had the problem licked, but as of this morning, the script will not run without errors. Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
Processing : C:\users\xxx\Desktop\ht\Automatic_Post-Call_Survey.htm
Exception calling "SaveAs" with "16" argument(s): "This is not a valid file name.
Try one or more of the following:
* Check the path to make sure it was typed correctly.
* Select a file from the list of files and folders."
At C:\users\xxx\Desktop\hd.ps1:11 char:20
+     $opendoc.saveas <<<< ([ref]"$docpath\$doc.FullName.doc", [ref]$saveFormat);
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

if "16" is the error code, that represents an inability to delete the directory...but it doesn't appear as if I'm asking for that at all--unless there's some default parameter in place somewhere. I'm pretty much baffled.anyone have any other ideas I can try out?

```
$docpath = "c:\users\xxx\desktop\do"
$htmPath = "c:\users\xxx\desktop\ht"

$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $htmPath -filter "*.htm*"
$saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatDocument"); 
$word = new-object -comobject word.application 
$word.Visible = $False        
$filename = ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))

function saveas-document   {         
        $opendoc = $word.documents.open($doc.FullName);         
    $opendoc.saveas([ref]"$docpath\$filename", [ref]$saveFormat);         
    $opendoc.close();
}       
ForEach ($doc in $srcfiles)     {
    Write-Host "Processing :" $doc.FullName         
    saveas-document        
    $doc = $null   
}   

$word.quit();
```

Comment: `$filename = e($_.fullname)....` what's the `e`? And `$_` is there because you are in a pipe?

Comment: @Christian I was hoping the the `e` was the source of all my problems; it is not. Good catch, though. Elimiating the `e` (as I've done in the edited code above) results in the same error message.

Comment: and what about `$_`, I can't see a piping in your code.... Test if `$filename` has a value... I think is `$null`

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding piping, but I thought `$_.fullname` was necessary to pull the filename from the MS-Word document(s) referenced in the preceding code rather than expecting that variable to come from elsewhere. Would it just need to be `$fullname`?

Comment: @Christian  I don't think so, I got tha same error code with `$fullname` substituted for `_.$fullname`

Comment: `$fullname` never has a value in your code...

Comment: OK...let me go back and hunt that down. As I said, I thought I was pulling the variable from the MS-Word object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do what do you need, but is not the best design :)

```
$docpath = "c:\users\xxx\desktop\do"
$htmPath = "c:\users\xxx\desktop\ht"


$srcfiles = Get-ChildItem $htmPath -filter "*.htm*"

$saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatDocument"); 

$global:word = new-object -comobject word.application 

$word.Visible = $False        

#$filename = ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))

function saveas-document ($docs)  {         
    $opendoc = $word.documents.open($docs);    
    $savepath = $docs -replace [regex]::escape($htmPath),"$docpath"
    $savepath = $savepath -replace '\.html*', '.doc'
    $opendoc.saveas([ref]"$savepath", [ref]$saveFormat);         
    $opendoc.close();
}       
ForEach ($doc in $srcfiles)     {
    Write-Host "Processing :" $doc.FullName         
    saveas-document  -doc  $doc.FullName     
    $doc = $null   
}   

$word.quit();
```

Comment: Works like a dream--except the file extension is remaining *.htm instead of *.doc. Do you know offhand if that's expected behavior? My guess is that it is, and I'll need to work in another method to change thje filename.

Comment: @dwwilson66 added a replace for extension.

Comment: You rock, @Christian. This is crazy helpful in getting me up to speed with PowerShell.

Comment: @dwwilson66 Glad to help! Take time to read this great online ebook: http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/ebookv2/default.aspx