# Recursively Changing File extensions from .docx and .pdf to .txt

Tags: powershell, pdf, recursion, doc

```
$findPDF = Get-ChildItem -Path "$fileDrive" -Filter *.pdf -r 
$findDOCX = Get-ChildItem -Path "$fileDrive" -Filter *.docx -r

$pullFiles += $findPDF
$pullFiles += $findDOCX
#[array]$pullFiles 

#$pullFiles.length

$holdPath = @()
for($i = 0; $i -lt $pullFiles.length; $i++){
        #get the full path of each document
        $fullPath = Resolve-Path $pullFiles.fullname[$i]
        #stores the information in a global array
        $holdPath += $fullPath.path
}
#$holdPath

<#
.DESCRIPTION Uses the word.APPLICATION object to open and convert the word documents into .txt.
#>

#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402898/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-save-as-a-different-file-extension
#wdFormatDOSTextLineBreaks  5   Microsoft DOS text with line breaks preserved.


foreach($fi in $holdPath){
    $Doc = $word.Documents.Open($fi.name)

    $NameDOCX = ($Doc.name).replace("docx","txt")
    $Doc.saveas([ref] $NameDOCX, [ref] 5)

    $NamePDF = ($Doc.name).replace("pdf","txt")
    $Doc.saveas([ref] $NamePDF, [ref] 5)

    $Doc.close()
}
```

**The problem Statement**
The program needs to get any pdf and doc/x file and convert it to a .txt file. Now, I am able to recursively search and pull all .docx and .pdf documents from the file system. Now, I just need to convert them.

**The Error**

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\fileExtRename.ps1:38 char:2
+     $Doc = $word.Documents.Open($fi.name)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\fileExtRename.ps1:40 char:2
+     $NameDOCX = ($Doc.name).replace("docx","txt")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

[ref] cannot be applied to a variable that does not exist.
At C:\Users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\fileExtRename.ps1:41 char:2
+     $Doc.saveas([ref] $NameDOCX, [ref] 5)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (NameDOCX:VariablePath) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonExistingVariableReference

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\fileExtRename.ps1:43 char:2
+     $NamePDF = ($Doc.name).replace("pdf","txt")
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

[ref] cannot be applied to a variable that does not exist.
At C:\Users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\fileExtRename.ps1:44 char:2
+     $Doc.saveas([ref] $NamePDF, [ref] 5)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (NamePDF:VariablePath) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonExistingVariableReference

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\fileExtRename.ps1:46 char:2
+     $Doc.close()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: The call to `$word.Documents.Open($fi.name)` failed, either because the file in `$fi.name` does not exist or because `$word` could not open it. You just assume that the open succeeded and proceed to use `$Doc` as valid without knowing if it is or not.  The invalid `$Doc` causes all calls using it to fail. You should *always* do some error checking, and your code does absolutely none. (Your question has absolutely nothing to do with *recursively changing file extensions*, BTW; it's about recursively *converting files*. Your title is incorrect.)

Comment: You aren't defining `$word` anywhere ? You need a `$word = new-object -ComObject Word.Application` somewhere before you can use it.

Comment: you should use `$word=new-object -ComObject Word.Application `and try `$word.documents.Open($fi.name,$true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$word variable are not initialized, and your are complicated for Nothing (without offense you). Modify all your script like this :

```
$fileDrive ="C:\temp"
$word = new-object -ComObject Word.Application 

Get-ChildItem -Path $fileDrive -file -r -Include "*.docx", "*.pdf"  | %{

    $Doc = $word.Documents.Open($_.FullName)

    $NameDOC = $_.FullName.replace(".docx",".txt").replace(".pdf",".txt")

    $Doc.saveas([ref] $NameDOC, [ref] 5)
    $Doc.close()

}

$word.Quit()
```

But i have doubt on convert pdf to .txt with Word application like this... I think you should use itextsharp libray  like [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1268809d-5dc6-4cd2-a97f-a26bc3ae3a8b/using-powershell-to-parse-a-pdf-file?forum=ITCG)

Comment: The problem is where I work we follow very stringent guidelines. I looked at `itextsharp` before and it would require a download. Now if this were to be used on 1000 different computers, it would be impractical to do it because it would take too much time to install it on every computer. Fortunately, we do have an application called CA that can push software to any computer within the Domain. That takes a lot of effort and jumping through loops though. So not an option.

Comment: For PDF it doesn't work. I think it needs specific codec in order to read the file. It does a conversion. Now the weird thing is, it is just replacing the extension. That isn't the right way to do it. If you were to do a `save as` on a .pdf to .txt it keeps the text.

Comment: you can install your dll on server and run PowerShell script on this server only

Comment: also, is there a way to redirect the .`saveas` to a folder in `tmp`?

Comment: yes replace by $NameDOC ="c:\tmp\" + $_.Name.replace(".docx",".txt").replace(".pdf",".txt")

Comment: I am getting an error with that syntax `This is not a valid file name.
Try one or more of the following:
* Check the path to make sure it was typed correctly.
* Select a file from the list of files and folders.
At C:\users\p617824\Documents\files\powershell\fileExtRename.ps1:23 char:5
+     $Doc.saveas([ref] $NameDOC, [ref] 5)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

Comment: Verify your path exists, i have created a directory temp into my C:\ and i have do it $NameDOC ="C:\temp\" + $_.Name.replace(".docx",".txt").replace(".pdf",".txt")    and it work

Comment: Never mind, I didn't see you had changed fullname to name, my bad

Comment: `sing ave maria tone` youuuuu areee aaaa gennnniuussss